# OP deletes code after question is solved / answered, what to do in these cases?

Tags: discussion

This is not the 1st time I see this happens.

But never read this at Meta.

OP gets an answer or accepts an answer and after that deletes his own code (maybe afraid of someone could make a bad use of it, or teacher would find it), but it's not the idea of SOF right?, the code should stay as it is, not being deleted.

You can check the [revision here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/23375995/revisions) of what I'm talking about, I just edited the question and readded the code. I know a rollback would be better but I've never found that option (maybe reputation or Idk), but that's not the point.

What procceeds in these cases? just readd code / rollback? Or what should be done here?

This time I wanna excuse myself 'cause I'm not used to post here (well 1st time actually) I'm trying to follow the same rules as SOF but Meta's still a bit confusing to me.

Comment: What you did was exactly correct.  You don't have a true "rollback" option as you don't have 2K rep.  But editing the code back in is a perfectly fine alternative.  Just make sure you leave a good edit comment (as you did in this case) so reviewers know why you are editing so much code into a question.

Comment: Ok, I solved 2 doubts in one post :) I need to reach 2k rep for "rollback" and this. Thanks

Comment: I believe this situation is described exactly in the above-linked question, which also leads to this one: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251923/what-to-do-when-an-op-asks-to-delete-my-code-from-my-answer . It's a relatively common occurrence on the site, unfortunately.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A radical change to the post's content is something that should be rolled back.  What that does is change the semantic meaning of the answers, and could potentially invalidate a few of them along the way.

If you see someone doing that, roll it back.  If they keep doing it, flag it for moderator attention too.

Comment: Yup; all correct, of course! Though no flagging is necessary here. The user had a history of doing this with all their questions, and I've... taken care of that.

Comment: Thanks Makoto and @AndrewBarber I'll have it in mind