# Should we roll back defaced deleted questions?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33455119/why-cant-index-html-call-javascript-css-and-html-includes-with-spring-mvc

I'd prefer to have questions maintain non-defaced state, even if they're deleted. I'm not sure if I can meaningfully articulate *why* I think that other than I'd rather have the "top level" view of a question be the question that got deleted rather than the subsequent defacing.

(I'm also not excited that the OP deleted all their comments leaving mine without context.)

Comment: What a weird guy. Check out [this history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/32020405/revisions) - it's so convulated and has so many revisions, I wouldn't know to what state to rollback.

Comment: @Jongware Whoa; never seen anything like *that* one before!

Comment: It should be rolled back to a point before it was originally posted.

Comment: @MartinJames For Halloween I dressed as a time traveler a year ago; I'll do it then.

Comment: @Jongware - Yep. Its weird alright. --> [Graph](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ZC4rX.jpg) of the length of the post by revision. [Interactive](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/383000/post-revision-history-character-count?PostId=32020405#graph)

Comment: I don't really see that the question has been deleted matters at all. The same basic rules would still apply; after all, if rollbacks should not be done on deleted questions, SO wouldn't make that an option (it'd be easy enough to disable). For the general question about rolling back defaced posts, see [Rolling back a “deleted” question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/141593), [User deleting code after question has been answered](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/108617), [What to do when the OP mutilates their own question?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114803)

Comment: Similar questions on Stack Overflow Meta: [OP deletes code after question is solved / answered, what to do in these cases?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253319) and [How do you rollback?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/271934), for example.

Comment: If you're not careful, you'll end up arguing that spam and other objectionable posts should not be modified so that their content is not visible.  Not all deleted material should be made visible.

Comment: You can, but unless you're voting to bring it back, I find it a waste of time. If it's deleted, and it's not going to come back, who cares? It's not like they're leaving [abusive messages](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/307280/dealing-with-inline-tantrums-from-users-whose-answers-werent-accepted/307283#307283) for anyone unfortunate enough to stumble upon them.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: https://yourlogicalfallacyis.com/slippery-slope

Comment: @BoltClock I remember one of those, it confused me. Meh-it's a waste of time but I can't help it :)

Comment: @JonathonLeffler Is that directed at me? I don't think I'll need to be very careful to avoid arguing that.

Comment: @Jongware that user also has some pretty strange things going on in his repuration graph... http://i.imgur.com/U3HrXAg.png

Comment: @DLeh: "User was deleted" is a thing

Answer (score 10):

You're absolutely right that posts shouldn't be defaced by anyone, including the OP, no matter in what state they are.

From section 3 of the [TOS](https://stackexchange.com/legal) *INAL*

> You agree that all Subscriber Content that You contribute to the Network is perpetually and irrevocably licensed to Stack Exchange under the Creative Commons Attribution Share Alike license. You grant Stack Exchange the perpetual and irrevocable right and license to use, copy, cache, publish, display, distribute, modify, create derivative works and store such Subscriber Content and to allow others to do so in any medium now known or hereinafter developed (“Content License”) in order to provide the Services, even if such Subscriber Content has been contributed and **subsequently removed by You**

From section 4 of the same document:

> Restrictions: …Under no circumstances will Subscriber use the Network or the Service to … (d) knowingly post any false, inaccurate or incomplete material.

Once posted you cannot remove the content. By doing so the OP is in violation of the ToS.

We might lose valuable content if anyone does this, which is another reason to keep the post, even deleted, in good shape.

Rolling back those defacing edits is a good call. If the user is in the process of defacing their own posts you can consider flagging for a moderator.

The only exception to this rule is SPAM and/or abusive flagged posts. Those are defaced by the system and tagged with a special post-notice.

Comment: I don't think it's a violation of TOS; it's still their content, just crappy content.

Comment: You can be my lawyer when I need to go to court ;)

Comment: @DaveNewton: I agree that it wouldn't be a violation under the cited language. However, note that in section 4 of the TOS, there is this statement: _"Under no circumstances will Subscriber use the Network or the Service to...(d) knowingly post any false, inaccurate or incomplete material."_. I'd say that defacing an answer that is otherwise useful, making it "false, inaccurate, or incomplete" would be a violation under that clause. I wouldn't myself post judgments about what is and what is not a violation of the TOS in a SO/SOM answer, but in this case I think the judgment probably is correct.

Comment: @PeterDuniho It was a question, not an answer :)

Comment: @DaveNewton: okay, change my comment to read _"I'd say that defacing a **question**..."_ then. Same difference :p. I was the one that (erroneously) introduced the word "answer", not the TOS.

Comment: That TOS passage obviously doesn't apply. The original version is still in the revision history. Nobody's "removed" it.

Comment: _"We might lose valuable content if anyone does this, which is another reason to keep the post, even deleted, in good shape."_ what

Comment: This answer is just plain nonsense. The TOS explains that even if the OP tries to remove the content, SO is still licensed to use the content, but that doesn't mean SO is *required* to use the content, nor does it make editing of posts a TOS violation. As for "false, inaccurate or incomplete" -- that's a stretch anyway, but for a question that is no longer relevant in any way to anyone, "bla bla bla" is just as complete as the original: it clearly indicates that there is no relevant content in the question.

Comment: Besides, even if such edits are a violation of the TOS, that's no reason to roll them back. If they are a violation of the TOS, then get lawyers involved, not users. The only time users need to get involved is to perform edits to get SO in a better state. You can make a reasonable argument that the rollback gets SO in a better state (though I wouldn't agree with it), so your conclusion can still be supported, but your line of reasoning is just not right.

Comment: I like the section 4 argument a little better from the "incomplete" standpoint. Ultimately it comes down to what Lightness said; it's an OCD thing for me. Still mulling the answers over.

Comment: @DaveNewton sure, take your time. I up voted the other answer.

Answer (score 5):

I do it, but only to satisfy my OCD. I acknowledge that this reverses the author's attempt to stave off embarrassment of their mistakes. Sorry! (Perhaps it'll encourage them to think harder before rushing to click the "Post" button next time.)

As BoltClock indicates, doing so is *largely* a waste of time … though for 10k+ users it's convenient to be able to see at a glance *what* was deleted.

Of course for particularly egregious content (e.g. spam, which is automatically obscured) [this is overridden by more important factors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307283/560648).

So, "should we"? I dunno mate. Do it if you want to. I don't think we "should" have a rule either way.

Comment: I'm so used to being stupid that it doesn't matter if I leave my dumb stuff up any more :/