# Rollback Etiquette when OP removes code from question after your answer is accepted

Tags: discussion, edits, etiquette, rollbacks

This question might be a duplicate of [OP deletes code after question is solved / answered, what to do in these cases? [duplicate]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253319/2333499), but I am not sure.

There is one significant difference between my situation and that of the referenced question; Frakcool did not have any investment in whether the question edit was rolled back or not.

In my case, I have the accepted answer on this question [How to get summation with count larger than certain amount](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42608988/2333499). This morning I received a down-vote and a comment saying that my answer was wrong.

When I checked the question, it had been edited to remove code and information relevant to the question, no new information was added. My course of action was to roll back the edit to the question and respond to the comment on my answer explaining what I did and why.

A user with 14k+ rep commented:

> First of all, you should **never rollback an edit made by an OP** just to prove your point. Secondly, your answer does not adequately address the opening problem statement that was there all the time and neither does the text that the OP deleted but which you rolled back make your answer right. It is just plain wrong either way. As an established user on SO you should know and accept that your only viable course of action is to delete your answer; ...

And rolled-back my rollback.

---

- Was it wrong for me (specifically, not any other user) to rollback that edit to a question (made by the OP) because I can be perceived as having something to gain from it? Or for any other reasons?
- What would my correct course of action been?

Comment: Pretty straight-forward, if there's any dispute over what the OP might have meant then the user with the answer mark on his post of course got it right.  If the question does not agree well with the accepted answer or is ambiguous then it needs to be edited.  You did so, well done.  That's the end of it.

Comment: On the 14k user's reply, aren't you disallowed from deleting your answer if it's upvoted and accepted?

Comment: The comment saying your answer was wrong because "the OP asked for names having had 3 or fewer transfers" is wrong.  The OP clearly stated in the question (in all versions) that people with more than 3 transfers should be included as long as the **largest** 3 (or fewer) of those transfers sum to at least 1024 - "Johnson is listed since Johnson account is listed because it has received 1112 USD in the following three transfers: 512 USD + 100 USD + 500 USD" (and Johnson also had a fourth transfer of 10 USD, not included in the sum)

Comment: @Izkata You can't delete an accepted answer; you can delete an upvoted answer.  Note though that if you really do think that your answer is harmful, even though it's accepted, you can flag for a mod to delete it.  They'll delete an accepted answer that the author wants deleted as long as they're confident that the author honestly thinks the answer is wrong, rather than them simply ragequitting or otherwise trying to vandalize their own answer.

Comment: @Servy `can_delete = !(upvoted && accepted)` is what I think is right, but am not sure.  I did a quick search on meta to see if I could answer my uncertainty myself, before posting the comment, but found a mix including one that sounded like if the answer is accepted but _downvoted_ (negative score) it could still be deleted

Comment: Edits made by the OP that invalidate existing reasonable answers are not ok. Sometimes, an OP will modify the question after the answers start rolling in because they realise people are misinterpreting the question, but even in that case they should be politely informed that they shouldn't do that. For an OP to make an invalidating edit after they've accepted an answer is extremely rude. OTOH, rollback wars get ugly quickly, so if a rollback war starts, get out quickly, and let the auto-flagging process take care of it.

Comment: @izkata The answer owner can delete it at any score but not if it's accepted. Any negatively scored answer can be deleted by 3 20k+ users (accepted or not).

Answer (score 80, accepted):

No, it wasn't wrong for you to roll back the edit.  It was wrong for the other user to rollback the question *again*.  Not all changes made by the OP are appropriate, and if the OP harms a post, it's *appropriate* to roll back that harmful change.  That you had posted an answer is certainly cause for you to be careful, and see if you are in fact biased, but it certainly doesn't mean you can't ever make such an edit.

Comment: @PeterDuniho An auto flag will be cast after the second rollback for a mod to look at it anyway.

Comment: _"An auto flag will be cast after the second rollback"_ -- really? didn't know that. Well, that'd be worth pointing out in the above. :)

Answer (score 6):

I agree with everyone else. One point I hadn't seen anyone explicitly make is that **questions are not solely for the use of the OP**. Stack Exchange is a community, and want to preserve answers for everyone who may come after.

A situation like this where the OP changes their question after having accepted another answer is similar to an OP trying to delete their question after they have solved their problem. Once a question gets past the possibility of being an easy dupe, answers come in, and one gets accepted, the question no longer solely belongs to the OP.

Comment: Chants "The greater good...."