# Is there anything to prevent users from deleting questions so nobody else can benefit from them?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I've seen this sort of thing happen on occasion in the past when doing edit reviews, but this was the first time I thought to grab the link from my history.  [A user had asked a question where (s)he had some back and forth which apparently resolved his/her issue.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23348192/objective-c-https-login-post-and-get-correct-url-status-code/23350414#23350414)  (S)he then attempted to hide the URLs (s)he was originally working with by editing the question and another user's answer.  After that edit was denied, (s)he deleted the question (hence that link won't work for non-moderators).

There are certainly legitimate reasons, such as accidental leaking private details or API keys, which would cause somebody to have to delete their own question.  But something like this seems like somebody using SO for personal benefit, and then removing content so nobody else will gain from their experience.  Is there any automated system to track/prevent this kind of abuse?  Is it even worth worrying about?

Comment: Related, in the sense that some of the remedies are similar: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251923/1906307

Comment: Related from MSE: [Does systematic self-deleting need to be prevented](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/74466)

Comment: This situation can be a bummer, but I'm not sure the particular question here really needs to be undeleted; it's little more than a typo. I think we can let it go. @WilliamAndrewMontgomery

Comment: Considering that the question pointed to live links (yes, it was a bad idea, but what's done is done) and the owner of the question wanted to kill them, I see no reason why we should prevent him from doing so. This isn't much different from someone accidentally or unknowingly posting sensitive data and wanting to remove it. Now it would be preferable that he'd replace it with a generalized version, rather than remove it completely, I wouldn't hold it against him, considering the nature of the problem in question.

Comment: @JeffMercado I felt, since the return codes of the URLs in question were a key part of resolving the question, removing them would cause the question to make much less sense.

Comment: Guys, I ended up rolling back both edits. The questioner may have wanted to hide the links, but also put an answer in their question, was called on it in comments, and left it there anyway. Editing *answers* to hide links should also neither be encouraged nor tolerated IMHO.

Comment: The part I would worry about is not the people trying to abuse the system by that, but about the people helping him by approving the edits

Comment: As a related curiosity .. say you accidentally put some private info in a question (example, internal URL etc).  Then you edit the question.  unfortunately the sensitive info is still findable in the edits.  As a curiosity, is there a solution to that problem?  Cheers

Comment: @Joe Blow: the solution is don't post sensitive info online in the first place. The Internet never forgets.

Comment: Wow Ian, thanks for that hugely informative answer about the technology of SO!  :)

Comment: Back in the universe, there would certainly already have been cases where someone accidentally posted something wildly confidential; their solicitors would have phoned through to SO and asked to have a fix put in.  I'm more just curious how common this is, is there already something in place, can high-moderators "delete edit history" etc.

Comment: (Also you can imagine cases if some fool putting something tremendously vulgar/racist/etc, or even say criminal or terrorism or whatever related, into an "edit history". It's a straightforward well-known problem on any pro-sumption site.)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Users are unable to delete questions that have an answer with a positive score.  If there is a valuable answer to the question, it'll generally have an upvote or two, which will prevent the question from being deleted.

On top of that, if a user is constantly deleting their questions they'll end up question banned after a bit, preventing them from asking new questions.

Vandalizing edits can of course be rejected, or rolled back.  The post author will be notified of their answer is vandalized in an edit, and the post will be bumped on the "active" list, providing visibility into these inappropriate actions.

Comment: I'm not sure that anonymizing a URL counts as "vandalism", especially on one's own post.

Comment: @JoshCaswell No, but a lot of people try to delete the entirety of the post, or remove so much of it that it becomes useless, since they can't delete it.  That is what I was referring to.

Comment: Thank you for the info.  I was unaware of those features built-in to prevent abuse.  All the more reason to take the time to upvote helpful answers.

Comment: @Servy - people try to delete the entirety of a post when they can't edit it.  What else can they do?  I have wanted to update or delete things posted.  On one site (not in the SE network), I couldn't delete a picture I posted -- it was being used to harass me, and the options wouldn't allow me to delete it, so I put a bogus pic in it's place that the admins would delete.  PARAGRAPH Comments on here are very much the same, if you try to hit RETURN to insert a blank line, it submits, and by the time you have finished editing the comment,  you find you can't.  So what to do?

Comment: @Astara I don't see how deleting the picture would be very helpful.  Anybody intent on using the pic against you surely would not rely on the pic being available in your post.  At the least, they'd copy the pic and post it somewhere under their own control.

Comment: @Jerry B: It was an anime art forum where the picture was moved from the, comparatively, heavy traffic'ed wallpaper group that people scan for downloads to a comparatively less traffic'ed, 'indy-art' group, that people visit less  often because its usually stuff that isn't desktop'ed sized or isn't something you'd use in a rotating background group of desktop wallpapers.  It was a political move on the level of a 20-something drama-soap.  I decided I didn't want to play such games, so wanted to remove it.  Not likely they'd repost someone else's artwork if the artist deleted it.

Comment: Similarly some sites play games with their bug trackers in going against common standards in bugzilla, et al. type bug trackers.  Usually the submitter of the bug can close a bug, and in a real bug-system like bugzilla, usually 'reopen' their own bug if it is closed, not addressing the issue.  Two places that violate such norms -- the perl issue tracker where you can't close your own bug nor reopen it, and the transmission bug/issue tracker where bug submissions have to be approved by a moderator before being accepted into the database.  Even their forum doesn't require such.

Comment: @Astara That's a case where you should be flagging for moderator attention and explaining the issue.

Comment: @Servy - If it was one of these forums where moderation is question-able, and moderate-able, yes, but some venues hold are not comfortable with distributed power and favor more a limited, 'cabal', or autocracy of a few or one, established, power-holders who want to protect their power by not having it diluted by newcomers.  The internet is rife with such fiefdoms (with many disguised as 'open' because the project uses 'open source').

Comment: *" If there is a valuable answer to the question, it'll generally have an upvote or two, which will prevent the question from being deleted."* - This assumption doesn't hold if the question is deleted three minutes after receiving the perfect answer...

Comment: @AndreyTyukin In that fairly uncommon case you can simply re-post the content, if you really feel it's that valuable.

Comment: @Servy The content itself might be not as valuable as the knowledge that the question asker tends to grab "teh codez" from the first answer, delete both Q&A, and then run. If I knew that it would happen, I wouldn't bother to answer in the first place. But I agree, it's rather uncommon, and it's rather a minor annoyance.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin If the answer would only ever have been useful to the post author, and not anyone else, then *the question wasn't appropriate for SO in the first place*.  If the answer was broadly applicable to the community as a whole, and wasn't already readily available (in other words, any question that you should actually have answered in the first place), then you should want to re-create it.

Comment: @Servy In the particular case that I had in mind when making this comment, voting to undelete both Q&A worked. Both the question and the answer are now upvoted, but I suspect that the asker wasn't after the upvotes.