# Why do authors of a question remove their question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, deleted-questions, etiquette

I have faced a question where I sat and tried things and solutions to the issue with the author of the question.

Then I made an answer and posted it. Shortly after, I was editing and adding some format to the answer, and the question got deleted!

Why do they delete their question when there is an answer and there might be someone in the future who would benefit? Is it just because they don't want to give an upvote or select as correct answer?

Is it selfishness?

What can I do to deal with this issue?

Edit: Here is the [Deleted SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37066352/i-cant-select-date-from-xdsoft-datetimepicker).

Comment: (anecdotally) Often because it is a homework assignment and they don't want to be caught out cheating.

Comment: I appreciate it, what about coding? And in case of homework assignment, is it allowed to post it here?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking about "what about coding?" and the fact that it is homework is irrelevant as to whether it is allowed. Questions should be judged on their merits. Objectively is it a good on topic question or not?

Comment: See [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255715/is-there-anything-to-prevent-users-from-deleting-questions-so-nobody-else-can-be)

Comment: I only delete my question if nobody answered it, and I found the solution in the meantime...

Comment: If it's an interesting, new and useful solution, you could self-answer it to help future users.

Comment: Add a link to the deleted question (you should be able to get that from your browser's history). If the rest of us deem it useful and on-topic we may undelete it.

Comment: Okay, thanks @Vin, I found my answer "Users are unable to delete questions that have an answer with a positive score." I am still sad that users are sometimes selfish.

Comment: I delete my question if I already found the answer. Usually on SO. :)

Comment: But what if someone else after lets say 10 days face the exact same problem, searched the internet multiple times and doesn't find anything. Wouldn't it be helpful to share what you found? I have completed so many projects using other peoples questions. Just thinking about how many people would benefit :)

Comment: That question doesn't look like a typical homework question. Maybe they just found the reason and couldn't be bothered to explain it. Or it was some silly reason that wouldn't benefit anyone else. Who knows? (Apart from the OP?)

Comment: Most likely the error was on the operator's side (as in PICNIC: "problem in chair, not in computer"). Imagine the embarrassment when OP just forgot to run the correct code ... Sorry to say that your answer isn't really good, as it does not seem to address the problem.

Comment: That question kinda sucked.  Looks like a typical "debug this for me" question. It's quite believable that someone who posts a question like that would rip off the work of other people.  Learn to identify bad questions, and don't bother answering them.  Downvote, vote to close, vote to delete questions like this.

Comment: If it makes you feel any better, deleting questions like that, right after it's answered, will eventually lead to a question ban if it's done enough.

Comment: Will, I understand now, thanks for explanation, I will try to do that ^_^

Comment: And thanks guys, I will be more careful on identifying good vs bad question