# New to Close Votes, user possibly defaced their question. What is the correct response?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, rollbacks

Today I just surpassed 3k reputation, so I started going though the Close Votes, and noticed something strange on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29829102/i-not-am-enter-e-to-enter-data-i-my-date-usi-hp).

At first I thought it might be an audit, but after looking carefully, it didn't appear to be the case.
Then I noticed that the question [had been edited](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/29829102/revisions), with all of the code stripped out, and previously correct grammar had been replaced with strangely suspect grammar and spelling in the title.

It seems that the user defaced their question, I just read [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251923/what-to-do-when-an-op-asks-to-delete-my-code-from-my-answer/251924#251924) that is possibly relevant in this case.

The question in it's original form was easily answered, and the answer was accepted.

I went ahead and voted to close (mainly because at the time I still thought it might be an audit).

The question is now `put on hold`, partly due to my vote.

Now I'm wondering if voting to close was the correct response in this situation.
Should I have rolled back the edit instead?  What is the correct response in this type of situation?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

First, is a user defaces their post, **roll it back.** If they do it again, roll it back again and flag for moderator attention.

The vote to close has no bearing on the actions needed on the post; if anything, that doesn't *help* the chances of the question getting reopened if a lot of valuable context is ripped out.

You did the right thing, now it's up to the OP to come back and revise the question to be on topic and clear.

Comment: 2nd case: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29837710/edit-data-from-mysql-using-php

Comment: Time to get a mod involved, I think.

Comment: @Makoto I'm on it

Comment: Yea, if I see that in close queue, I just open question in another tab, investigate, rollback if necessary, then just skip the question in the close queue.