# Why is this (heavily downvoted) question got deleted despite numerous answers with very positive votes?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions, closed-questions

Refer to this question [Finding the maximum value of an array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22544387/3834) which has now been closed and deleted. As an unfortunate consequence of being deleted, it is now visible to only users with 10K reputation.

This is a heavily downvoted question.

BUT it is also a question with a lot of positively upvoted answers, and more than 21K views.

Such a question is providing tremendous value to the programming community, notwithstanding with the massive downvotes the question receives; we can know this fact for sure by looking at the upvotes on the answers and the views.

So why is it deleted? *Can we as a community make an effort to undelete it?*

Comment: There are no other better "finding the maximum value of an array" questions with good answers?

Comment: It was deleted a year ago. Where did it turn up that you now notice?

Comment: While it's really a bad question, I have seen worst that are still available, but closed. In the specific case, I'm in favor of closing, not deleting.

Comment: It did go through SOCVR: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/search?q=22544387&room=90230 and I pinged the folks that deleted it. I was one of the close voters there.

Comment: Yeah, without that question and its answers, [how is anyone ever going to figure out how to find the maximum value in an array using C#](https://www.google.com/search?q=maximum+value+array+c%23+site:stackoverflow.com)?

Comment: so now we undeleted it for the 3rd time? Awesome.

Comment: I passed that to delete, the reason was simple. *When our programming fellows search for,  "c# Finding the maximum value of an array" is this what we like to present?* I bet we have something better to offer, my conclusion was "it is not making internet a better place" other then the fun to speculate about the downvotes.

Comment: @PetterFriberg, downvote it for all your like, but don't delete it. And although the question may not, but the answers are indeed making the internet a better place, as evident by the upvotes the answers receive and the views the question garners.

Comment: @rene, I do hope that the folks at SO are less fanatical about closing and deleting questions ( and hence making the internet less useful to all), more fanatical about making SO useful to programmers, not just to themselves.

Comment: @Graviton I did judge the whole Q/A, I did judge the views (poor fellows ending up on that), I would vote to delete it again but will refrain only because I don't like to vote 2 times on any question. You think people should be directed to this question, well ok with me, I will respect that

Comment: @PetterFriberg, if they think that the question is useful, who am I to stop them from coming to it?

Comment: I'm as fanatical as I can be.

Comment: Who am I stop? *trusted user with delete privs?*

Comment: @Graviton: 150 think that the question is not useful. That's why they downvoted. Only 38 think that the answer is useful. Does it contain anything that isn't also covered by this [well written Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101841/linq-how-to-perform-max-on-a-property-of-all-objects-in-a-collection-and-ret/1101931)

Comment: @BDL, if you feel that the question is not useful, then downvote it by all means-- there is no need to delete it because doing so will delete the answers, _which a lot of others are finding it useful_

Comment: The upvotes/downvotes on that was blown into huge numbers due to meta effect coming from this post https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251923/4099593. I have locked it for a small duration, to let meta decide whether to keep it or not.

Comment: @BhargavRao - please look at [the timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/22544387/timeline) to see that this question got ~100 DVs long after the meta voting took place.  Surely this Q+A is getting found by the googlers, the title is especially misleading, and they are not happy with with they got.  No surprise.  Deletion is therefore the correct resolution.

Comment: Aaand it's gone (again)

Answer (score 27):

> Such a question is providing tremendous value to the programming community

I contest this characterization of the question.

As Bhargav mentioned in the comments, this question's view and vote count is partially based on the Meta Effect due to [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251923/what-to-do-when-an-op-asks-to-delete-my-code-from-my-answer). That is, someone on MSO posted a question about it, which got it lots of attention.

The question itself is... *terrible*. The title itself has absolutely nothing to do with *any* of the problems that the given code has. The code given is just incredibly bug riddled (note that the `for` loop has no braces around the following code, thus meaning it only loops over the *first statement* following it).

If a person is searching for how to "find the maximum value of an array", this question *will not help them*. That is the opposite of "providing tremendous value to the programming community". We are building a database of searchable problems and solutions. This question does not provide a good correlation between its stated problem and the actual problem in the code, so it doesn't help anyone who has that problem find the solution.

It's a crap question. Let it die.

> we can know this fact for sure by looking at the upvotes on the answers and the views.

The Meta Effect notwithstanding, views counts and answer votes are not, in and of themselves, sufficient reason to keep a question around. This question was originally asked almost *five years ago*; of course it has a relatively high view count and vote totals.

That doesn't mean it isn't a garbage question. You never try to defend the question on its merits; you only defend it based on statistics.

People don't come to SO for statistics. They come to SO because of good questions with good answers. And if this is a bad, closable question, it should be closed and deleted.

Comment: Nicol Bolas for moderator!

Comment: Josh Caswell for moderator!

Comment: Cody Gray for... oh, wait...

Answer (score 13):

Been busy this morning, but I wanted to address a couple of things not addressed by the other answers

## This wasn't closed as a duplicate

Normally, we try to leave duplicate questions up if they're decent and can help point people to other, better answers. This question was NOT closed as a duplicate, but Unclear. Duplicate closure existed back then, yet the closers didn't pick that one. That's a pretty strong signal that something else is wrong here.

## It got a LOT of non-Meta downvotes

So Meta effect played a role in the current score, but looking at the [timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/22544387/timeline) I see one MAJOR feature. Do you see it too? Day after day it attracts **downvotes**, even **years after having been asked**. I'm no C# guy, but it doesn't take one to notice this question isn't good. Especially when you consider your own point

> BUT it is also a question with a lot of positively upvoted answers, and more than 21K views.

After 5 years it continues to sink into the mire. Contrast it with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13755007/c-sharp-find-highest-array-value-and-index), ostensibly about the same subject. 192k views, +56/-2 on the Q and +94/-1 for the top answer, and it's only some 18 months older than the one you linked. "Tremendous value" for the question and answer is pretty overstated here.

## Is the answer worth salvaging?

In an ideal situation, it would be preferred to merge the good answers with a duplicate question and just remove the question, but the answer looks too niche to move (without the question it loses all context). I'm no C# guy so I can't be sure. I won't vote to delete it anymore, but if I were the answerer (who has voted to undelete it 3 times) I'd consider making it more generic and trying to get it moved to another question. I'd really like to hear from them as to why this question needs to remain.

Answer (score 12):

This is why I think this particular question should be removed from Stack Overflow.

As we [now](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/381081/why-is-this-heavily-downvoted-question-got-deleted-despite-numerous-answers-wi#comment676233_381081) know the question have been heavily influenced by the [meta effect](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269349/what-is-the-meta-effect), both gathering massive amount of downvotes but probably also upvotes on answer.

*Now that all that have finished?, what are we left with?*

A question that ask "Finding the maximum value of an array?", but with an exception System.Convert.ToInt32(string, int)' is a 'method', which is not valid in the given context". A debug question (maybe even on-topic), with a debug answer.

Considering this, my reasoning to delete it was, this question makes internet a worse place because:

It has abnormal voting (I probably did not know the reason why), we may risk that it is presented in searches like "c# Finding the maximum value of an array" or "c# System.Convert.ToInt32(string, int)' is a 'method', which is not valid in the given context" and not only would people not understand the voting, but also this question is not suitable for this instead we have much better content.

I'm sorry that OP posting the answer may lose the reputation, but my overall concern was presenting correct content to other C# programmers searching for answers on internet.

Overall however if you can edit the question, create some kind of searchable/useful content (I don't think current downvotes/upvote reflect this) please feel free to do so, if a part even a small part of the community think it is useful I will look the other way.

Comment: no reputation would have been lost for the answerer since answer is older than 90 days.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre *well yeah it was 1 year ago that I voted to delete, but true answer was even more old* Anyway I will leave it in answer as a slogan "useful content before reputation" :)